# Azure Stream Analytics SU % Utilization keeps increasing

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am using Stream Analytics for a simple Data pass-through scenario.
Job has multiple SQL Server outputs (three) and one EventHub input. Event count is small. The problem is my SU % Utilization keeps increasing. My temporary solution is to restart Job once or twice a day.

Am I doing something wrong? Below is a sample of my query. I tried to change queries to use TUMBLINGWINDOW, but I got same result.

```
SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5
INTO [out-alias-1]
FROM [in-alias]
WHERE field_1 LIKE 'Event1:%' OR field_1 LIKE 'Event2:%';

SELECT field_1, field_3, field_6, field_7, field_8
INTO [out-alias-2]
FROM [in-alias]
WHERE field_1 LIKE 'Event3:%' OR field_1 LIKE 'Event4:%';

SELECT field_1, field_3, field_4, field_9, field_10
INTO [out-alias-3]
FROM [in-alias]
WHERE field_1 NOT LIKE 'Event1:%' AND field_1 NOT LIKE 'Event2:%'
  AND field_1 NOT LIKE 'Event3:%' AND field_1 NOT LIKE 'Event4:%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may observe a baseline SU % utilization with few or even without input events, because the system consumes certain amount of resource. The amount of resource consumed by the system may also fluctuate over time.

Streaming Units (SUs) represent the resources and power to execute an Azure Stream Analytics job. SUs provide a way to describe the relative event processing capacity based on a blended measure of CPU, memory, and read and write rates. Each streaming unit corresponds to roughly 1MB/second of throughput. For details, [Stream Analytics key concepts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-key-concepts/).

The SU % Utilization metric is an indicator for the need to scale an Azure Stream Analytics job. High SU % Utilization may be a result of large window in a query, large events in input, large out of order tolerance window, or a combination of the above. Partitioning the query, or breaking down the query into more steps, and adding more SUs from the Scale tab are both strategies to avoid such a condition.  For details, see [Scale Azure Stream Analytics jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-scale-jobs/).

Comment: The problem I have is my job has small number of events (< 1000 per hour) and small window in a query, but SU % utilization still keeps increasing.

Comment: @uross did you ever find a solution for this problem. I'm currently experiencing the same and there is a lack off documentation about this subject